# Webbrowser connection over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

is ist possible to make a connection to a "master" (not internet) over a browser using bluetooth? I want to make a service possibility to a device without creating an App (or just a invisible "driver" App if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged it as bluetooth-lowenergy I'm going to assume you're trying to do something with that...  And in that case, I don't think there's any direct way for a browser to access a low-energy device.  You'd have to develop some sort of application that would act as a translator between the low-energy interface and something the browser would understand like a web server.

Comment: Would it be possible with tho "normal" Bluetooth?

Comment: Same problem.  Web browsers are for communicating with HTTP (usually over the internet).  Bluetooth is a protocol that uses a radio and has no concept of HTTP.  They're completely different things.  You'd have to write a program that bridged the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth and WiFi are very similar radio technologies (even using the same frequencies), but WiFi can transport TCP/IP/HTTP to support internet browsing, while I'm not aware of Bluetooth (LE or normal) being able to do that.